# php Child Class does inherits empty object

Tags: php

I am setting a parents class properties like so:

```
class Parent {
    protected $object;
    protected $childObject;
    function __construct() {
        $this->object = new Object();
        //I can access the objects methods here
        $this->childObject = new Child();
    }
}
```

but when i try to access in the child I get `all to a member function method() on a non-object` when i try to access the method.

```
class Child extends Parent {

    function __construct() {
        $this->object->method();
        //But here I just get NULL
    }
}

class Object extends Parent {
     public function method() {
        //do stuff
     }
}
```

And the parent class is being initiated after all the classes are declared.

Comment: Show us where / how you are instantiating stuff.

Comment: Also if you are just instantiating the child you never call the parent's constructor

Comment: Answer it @Rizier123...

Comment: Updated with initiation code.

Comment: You still don't call the parent constructor!

Comment: @Rizier123 I'm creating a new instance of the parent, which calls the constructor.  `parent::__construct();` causes a stackoverflow!

Comment: @FrankAstin Please show us your **full** and **real** code also how you create your instance

Comment: @Rizier123 That's all there is, just a few more methods in the object.

Comment: @FrankAstin So you create a instance from Parent? (BTW: 1. Don't use keywords like Parent as class names! 2. You do some weird inheritance! )

Comment: Only `$this->object = new Object();` and `class Object extends Parent` creates a infinite loop! Because How can you extend from a class where the property is a instance of the class? class inception !!!

Comment: @Rizier123 fair point

Comment: @FrankAstin And it's only the beginning! You have a paradise for Inceptions

Comment: But even if if object doesn't extend parent, it still doesn't inherit .

Comment: @FrankAstin If you don't extend the child also doesn't inherit from anything! (I have to say it, but your code just looks like a mess and it's very unclear what your goal is!)

Comment: Child still extends parent, but object does not.

Comment: @Rizier123 you're right, I'm going to start from scratch on this one.

Answer (score 0):

You also have to call the parent constructor in order to assign the object to the property, like this:

```
class Child extends Parent {

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
      //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ See here I call the constructor of the parent
        $this->object->method();
    }
}
```

For more information about constructors and destructors see the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php